# Duplicate Apps installed (Slack)

Tags: uninstall, delete, duplicate

I have started to use Linux a few months back so I'm a novice user. Recently I came accross this issue where I have managed to install two duplicate apps, one through the official app website and the other through the ubuntu software app. I installed them from different sources because for some reason, one of the sources showed the app is still in beta and the other showed the stable version for download so obviously I required a stable version.

So my question is, how do I remove the app downloaded and installed through the website? I can uninstall the 1st copy of the app from the ubuntu store but not able to uninstall the original one which I downloaded through the web. I have tried the commands using terminal but the app still remains. Btw, the app name is "Slack" if that helps.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove slack
```

This can help you by removing slack from your machine and then try re-installing it. Though I think it won't effect you that much!! Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the revert!. When I run this command on the terminal, is returns this: Package 'slack' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.   But I can clearly see slack in my apps and It is fully functional too.

Comment: Try using synaptic package manager to remove the program and reboot your machine!! If you don't have one, will recommend to just install it as it will be useful in future purpose also.

Comment: Well Thanks! It worked! I was able to identify and remove the app through synaptic package manager without any issues. I don't know why I wasn't able to remove it from the terminal though. My theory is that it might have been installed from a different name other than slack.